# Updating Silverlight DataGrid When Underlying Data Changes

Tags: silverlight

I am binding a DataGrid with the following code and all appears to be working when adding or removing rows in the code-behind - the gird automatically displays the added or removed rows as expected.  However, upon user clicking a button in the page I am grammatically updating a column in all the records.  Those updates are NOT immediately updated in the grid so I am trying to find the way to do this.  Is it a matter or rebinding to grid or is there something automatic because of the observablecollection that should be handling this?

```
// Get the Disaster ID selected
_selectedDisaster = (DisasterEvent)combo.SelectedItem;


// Return volunteers that have been selected 
// And populate the grid
Binding b = new Binding("");
b.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
b.Source = DisasterEvent_Volunteers;


this._grid_SelectedVolunteers.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, b);
this._grid_SelectedVolunteers.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data items should implement interface INotifyPropertyChanged. You can find more information in this good article. http://jesseliberty.com/2012/06/28/c-5making-inotifypropertychanged-easier/

Comment: Yes!I needed to add that to my underlying data class.  It is not enough just to rely on the ObservableCollection.  Thanks for the reminder!!